Can I propagate peony from root pieces?

I dug out two peonies and got some broken root pieces. Can I propagate from the root pieces in the pot?


This is a slow process, but not difficult. When propagating peonies through root cuttings, you'll be choosing fleshy root sections – not portions of the plant's crown. Each root cutting should be at least one-half inch around and six inches long. For best results, use a very clean, sharp knife to make your cuts. source. AKA the first google entry.

